# Material-ui Google Maps Place Component Doesn't Keep Text When Placed In My Custom Function

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

React/NextJS/Material-UI newbie issue, hoping someone can share some insight. I'm using Material-ui Google Maps Place component (https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#google-maps-place) out-of-the-box, nothing custom. But for some reason it doesn't work when wrapped inside of my custom function HideOnScroll, as shown below, which just hides my header onScroll. It will render and fetch Google places but it will only accept one character and then immediately goes back to null/original state upon typing second character. But it works perfectly when outside of this HideOnScroll function. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong? My guess is it's a state issue but I'm not clear on how to resolve it.

**My custom function:**

```
const HideOnScroll = (props) => {
        const { children } = props;
        const trigger = useScrollTrigger();
        return (
          <Slide appear={false} direction="down" in={!trigger}>
            {children}
          </Slide>
        );
      }
```

**This works:**

```
return (
    <header>     
        <AppBar className={header}>
          <div className={topTrim}></div>
          {mobileView ? displayMobile() : displayDesktop()}  
          <div>{GoogleMaps()}</div>         
        </AppBar>           
    </header>
  );
```

**This does not work:**

```
return (
    <header>
      <HideOnScroll {...props}>
        <AppBar className={header}>
          <div className={topTrim}></div>
          {mobileView ? displayMobile() : displayDesktop()}
          <div>{GoogleMaps()}</div>
        </AppBar>
      </HideOnScroll>      
    </header>
  );
```

FYI, the displayDesktop() function is below and I'm currently just trying to get this to work on desktop. I have also tried adding {GoogleMaps()} to this function as well but still experienced the same problem.

```
const displayDesktop = () => {
    return (      
      <Toolbar className={toolbar}>        
        <div className={toolBarTop}>{logo()}</div>                     
      </Toolbar>      
    );
  };
```

Comment: Are `displayMobile()`, `displayDesktop()` and `GoogleMaps()` React Functional Components, or standard js functions?

Comment: @kausko displayMobile() and displayDesktop() are functions but they do make use of material-ui ToolBar. I'm currently only trying to get this to work on desktop and the displayDesktop() function is as follows:

`const displayDesktop = () => {
    return (      
      <Toolbar className={toolbar}>        
        <div className={toolBarTop}>{logo()}</div>                     
      </Toolbar>      
    );
  };`

You can see the full GoogleMaps() function at [link]https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#google-maps-place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GoogleMaps` is a React functional component, and it must not be treated as a normal function. Since it is called like a normal function in JS, it no longer retains its properties as a component and loses its state and lifecycle methods. (This means your hooks will stop working too)

To fix this, consider calling the functional component using the angular bracket syntax, i.e. `<GoogleMaps/>`.

Also, by convention, the names of all user-defined components should start with a capital letter to distinguish them from regular/pre-defined components.

[This article](https://dev.to/igor_bykov/react-calling-functional-components-as-functions-1d3l) deals with this exact issue with details.

Comment: That was indeed the issue. I'm sure this was covered somewhere in my react Udemy course but I totally didn't think about this. I'm still learning and this is gold. Thank you so much for your help. I will read up on that article you shared.